# Invalid read of size 4 during pushing to vector

Tags: c++, vector

Hi there I have an error from valgrind:

```
==19383== Invalid read of size 4
==19383==    at 0x57F69FB: xy(int, int) (Generator.cpp:228)
==19383==    by 0x57F71E2: getNext() (Generator.cpp:164)

             . . .
             . . .


==19383==  Address 0x90ddbec is 4 bytes before a block of size 4 alloc'd
==19383==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==19383==    by 0x57FE9B7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /xx.so)
==19383==    by 0x57F79BA: allocate (new_allocator.h:104)
==19383==    by 0x57F79BA: allocate (alloc_traits.h:357)
==19383==    by 0x57F79BA: _M_allocate (stl_vector.h:170)
==19383==    by 0x57F79BA: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (vector.tcc:412)
==19383==    by 0x57F6F49: push_back (stl_vector.h:923)
==19383==    by 0x57F6F49: reset() (Generator.cpp:142)

             . . .
             . . .

==19383==    by 0x40A8FC: main (main.cpp:24)
==19383== 
==19383== 
==19383== ---- Attach to debugger ? --- [Return/N/n/Y/y/C/c] ----
```

and reset() function looks like:

```
void reset()
{
    this->first = true;

    std::vector<int>* counts = this->counts_iterator.getNext();
    (*this->picks).clear();

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->variant->groups.size(); i++)
    {
        (*this->picks).push_back(std::vector<int> ());
        for(int j = 0; j < (*counts)[i]; j++)
        {
            (*this->picks)[i].push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Before the call of function reset() is made this call:

```
this->picks = new std::vector<std::vector<int> > ();
```

there are definitions of variables:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >* picks;
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you newing vectors?  You could just store them in another vector or use a smart pointer.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating vectors? I've never come across a situation where that was a valid thing to do. A vector of vector, sure I've done that, but newing a single one? I dont see much point to that.

Comment: :D good point, well I came back to c++ after 4 years, and I do not need them now... Anyway it will prob. solve my problems, but I would like to understatnd what caused an error here

Comment: Where you have a `push_back()` of a `std::vector`, what happens if you split that up?  That is, allocate a `std::vector` on the stack, giving it a variable name, and passing that name to `push_back()`.  I expect this won't solve your problem, but it may provide a small clue.

Comment: You're misreading the valgrind output. The error is in `xy`, not in `reset`.

Comment: @ecatmur you were right, if you will post it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ecatmur said the problem was somewhere else, in file xy.cpp as valgrind said...